# A stronger version of the Erdös-Faber-Lovasz conjecture?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, lo.logic

For any set $X$ we set $[X]^2 = \big\{\{x,y\}: x,y \in X, x\neq y\big\}$.

Consider the following statement (S):

**Statement (S)** : Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite undirected graph and $V_1, \ldots, V_n\subseteq V$ with the following properties:

- $V = V_1\cup\ldots\cup V_n$,
- $E \subseteq [V_1]^2 \cup \ldots \cup [V_n]^2$, that is every member of $E$ is "inside" some $V_i$,
- for $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we have $\chi(G_i) = n$ where $G_i = (V_i, E\cap [V_i]^2)$, and
- for $i\neq j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we have $[V_i]^2\cap [V_j]^2 \cap E = \emptyset$, that is, $V_i$ and $V_j$ share no common edge.

**Then** we have $\chi(G) = n$.

(Statement (S) ends here.)

**Questions.**

1. Is (S) provably false?
2. If not, does the [Erdös-Faber-Lovasz conjecture (EFL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Faber%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_conjecture) imply (S)? Note that clearly (S) is a (possibly false) statement implying (EFL).

Comment: What if $G$ is a triangle, and $V_1,V_2$ are couples of its vertices?

Comment: You probably meant $[V_i]^2\cap [V_j]^2\cap E =\emptyset $ ?

Comment: Correct, @max, will correct this

Comment: @FedorPetrov You are right - I forgot the requirement that $E \subseteq [V_1]^2 \cup \ldots \cup [V_n]^2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is false already for $n=2$. Take a 5-cycle 12345 and sets 123, 3451.